# Regular expression , extract groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to verify if a value checks one of following formats : `..A , B.. , A..B`

and also retrieve the values: `(null, A) , (B, null) , (A, B)`

This is my code:

```
var regexRange = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$");

function getRangeValues(value) {
    var from = null;
    var to = null;
    var matches = regexRange.exec(value);
    if (matches !== null) {
        if (matches[3] !== undefined) {
            to = matches[3];
        }
        else if(matches[1]!==undefined && matches[1]!=='') {
            from = matches[1];
            if (matches[2] !== undefined && matches[2] !== '') {
                to = matches[2];
            }
        }
    }    
    var range = { From: from, To: to };
    return range;
}

Value: 1233 => From=12, To=null
```

I don't understand why i get this incorrect behavior, for other use cases it seems to work.

Comment: _"I don't understand why i get this incorrect behavior"_ - Which incorrect behaviour? Are you talking about an input of "1233"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i am talking about

Comment: Using the backslashes indeed seems to do the trick. Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't escape the backslashes in the string literal that you created the regex from. Inside a string literal you need `\\.\\.` if you want the resulting regex to have `\.\.`:

```
var regexRange = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$");
```

Single backslashes in a string are ignored if they're not followed by a character that needs escaping, so you were creating a regex that contained `..` which matches any two characters. Easier to use a regex literal:

```
var regexRange = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;
```

(Of course there could be other issues, but that one jumped out at me.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way instead.You can split the input and then validate it

```
var output=value.split("..");
var from=output[0];
var to=output[1];
if(from.length>=1 || to.length>=1)
{
if(from.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)==-1 && to.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)==-1)//valid
else //invalid
}
else//invalid
```

Comment: "Why use regex", indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your regex can be simplified. Consider this code:

```
str='..A , B.. , A..B';
re = /(\w*)\.\.(\w*)/g;
var arr = [];
var match;
while (match = re.exec(str))
   arr.push([ match[1]=="" ? null:match[1], match[2]=="" ? null:match[2] ]);
console.log(arr);
// OUTPUT: [[null, "A"], ["B", null], ["A", "B"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify things a lot:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

would match all three cases you proposed and capture everything in the correct groups (if present). However, it would also match `..` which you probably don't want. So, we can add a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure at least one alnum character is present:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

Then you can do

```
var myregexp = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
     var from = match[1]
     var to = match[2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it doesn't seem to work. I get undefined, undefined for A, A.., A..B

Comment: @gigi: Did you use the literal regex constructor in my code, or did you paste the regex into your string (which has the problem with backslashes as noticed by nnnnnn)?